# Cannot return objects in @dataProvider PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, testng-dataprovider

Is it allowed to return objects from `@dataProviders` to test methods?

```
public function iOsMessages()
{
    return [
        'update available'        => [1, new UpToDateMessage(), 'pl'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @test
 * @dataProvider iOsMessages
 */
public function success_create_message_for_ios(int $appVersion, MobileMessage $message, string $locale)
{
(...)
```

Error:

> The data provider specified for Tests\Tests\Mobile\Classes\AppVersionTest::success_create_message_for_ios is invalid.
>   Class 'Mobile\Classes\Messages\UpToDateMessage' not found

`MobileMessage` is an interface, imports are correct.

Comment: The error message says the class doesn't exist. PHPUnit is not guilty for that. Check the configuration of the autoloader and/or the class name and namespace.

Comment: Just remember that the data providers are executed only once before all the tests from a test case.

Comment: @axiac Does it make any difference? Those providers are used only once in separate tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers):

> A data provider method must be public and either return an array of arrays or an object that implements the Iterator interface and yields an array for each iteration step.